# Tomcat server not starting on eclipse while working on netbeans...!

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

Is it possible to run tomcat server in netBeans and eclipse IDE together on the same PC? I've configured tomcat server with netBeans but not able to start server on eclipse please let me know how if it is possible.

Comment: In short: yes, you can. It would be better if you post the exceptions in the log file of tomcat instead.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to start tomcat from both Netbeans and Eclipse at the same time?

Comment: Yes i am trying to start tomcat from both at same time.!

Comment: Then you cannot. Explained in duffymo's answer. It's like trying to turn the same TV using two remote controllers at the same time: one will do, the other won't.

Comment: Ok and thanks for the nice example.!

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans and Eclipse are both IDEs that let you run Tomcat inside them.

If you mean running either one or the other with Tomcat, that's no problem.

If you mean "at the same time", you'll have to tell each Tomcat instance to listen on a different port.